# Rounding a real number w.r.t. a given amount of steps

Tags: discrete-mathematics, mathematical-modeling, economics

Let $x$ be a real number, $x \in [0,1]$. Suppose a system can only provide a noisy signal about the value of $x$, given the granularity allowed by the system, $N \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

I'm looking for an equation/formula to round up $x$ given the number of steps $N$ existing within $[0,1]$. See example below.

**Example**

$x = 0.3$

$N = 2$, meaning that within the range [0,1] the system can only take either the value of $0$ or $1$. Given this granularity, the system should "round up" $x$ to $0$.

$N=5$, the system can now take the values $0$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{3}{4}$, $1$. Given this new granularity, $x$ should become $\frac{1}{4}$.

EDIT: Preferably not using floor or ceiling functions, i.e.

$$\frac {\lfloor x \cdot N \rfloor}{N -1}$$

Comment: Instead of floor you can use $\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \bmod(x,1)$...which is essentially the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function for calculating *floor*:

$$f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\arcsin(\sin(\pi(x-\frac{1}{2})))}{\pi}$$

---

Then, for your purpose, you can simply use:

$$\frac{f(xN)}{N-1}$$

---

If it helps, then you can also use the following function for calculating *ceiling*:

$$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan(\tan(\pi(-x-\frac{1}{2})))}{\pi}$$

---

If memory serves correctly, these functions yield incorrect results for negative integers.

Your question, however, implies that you are interested only in positive real numbers...

Comment: Thanks @barak manos. Expressing the floor [edited] as a function should do the job !

Comment: @flo: I'll add the *ceiling* function as well in that case...

Comment: Sorry @barak manos. Had in mind floor and wrote ceiling. But yes, feel free to add the ceiling one too. Could be of any help in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @flo: You're welcome :) Please note that these functions yield incorrect results for negative integers (if my memory serves me correctly). Your question, however, implies that you are interested only in positive real numbers...

Comment: Yes, I'm only considering positive real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[$$\frac{\lfloor x\cdot N \rfloor}{N-1}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%28x*5%29%2F4%2C+x%3D+0+to+1) should fit your needs...but if you don't like floor use $\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \bmod(x,1)$ instead...

Comment: Thanks @draks. I'm trying to avoid any floor or ceiling expressions (if possible) to make the model easier to solve in terms of equilibria.

Comment: @flo but you're right about $N-1$...